# Can't find pyside-uic when PySide was installed using Enthought Python and Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside, enthought

I installed PySide using:

```
enpkg pyside
```

(I'm using Mac OS X)

but I can get `pyside-uic`

```
$ pyside-uic
bash: pyside-uic: command not found
```

How can I have this command available.

```
 $ which python
 /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python

 $ which enpkg
 /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/enpkg

 $ python --version
 Python 2.7.3 -- EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)

 $ enpkg --version
 enstaller version: 4.6.4
```

Comment: what is the output of `which python`, `which enpkg`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with pyside-uic, I finally located it (through the `locate` command) and found it as pyside-uic-2.7 . Then the command `pyside-uic-2.7 -o test.py test.ui` worked fine.